# How to compile variable names using Symfony's ExpressionLanguage?

Tags: php, api, symfony

I am working with Symfony's ExpressionLanguage and trying to compile a statement like `a + b` where `a = 3`, `b = 4`.   How can I do so?

This code works okay:

```
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage;

$language = new ExpressionLanguage();

print($language->evaluate('a + b', array(
    'a' => 3,
    'b' => 4
)));  //prints '7'
```

But this code throws an error:

```
print($language->compile('a + b', array(
    'a' => 3,
    'b' => 4
)));
```

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\SyntaxError: 
Variable "a" is not valid around position 1.
in vendor\symfony\expression-language\Parser.php on line 204
```

Line 204:  https://github.com/symfony/expression-language/blob/3.1/Parser.php#L204

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah the syntax seems to be this:

```
print($language->compile('a+b', array(
    'a',
    'b'
)));

//prints ($a + $b)
```

**Q:  Can you pass values?**

Yes

```
print($language->compile("a + b + 15", array(
    'a',
    'b'
)));

//prints (($a + $b) + 15)
```

**Q:  Can you use a variable when it doesn't exist?**

You can, but it's better when you define it previously.  You are in control here.  If you don't define it, it's like using a variable in a native PHP without previously defining it.

There is a difference in `compiling` and `evaluating` too.

```
$data['a'] = $language->evaluate("3");
$data['b'] = $language->evaluate("3");
$data['c'] = $language->evaluate('a + b', array(
    'a' => 3,
    'b' => 4
));

echo $language->compile('a + b', array(
    'a',
    'b'
)) . ' = ' . $data['c'];  // prints ($a + $b) = 7

/*
$data => Array
(
   [a] => 3
   [b] => 3
   [c] => 7
)
*/
```

Comment: So you cannot pass values? You just pass the variable names and hope a value exists?